# The difference between BIOS time and boot time?

Tags: hard-drive, ssd, bios

My system is running on a hard drive and it takes more than a minute to boot into the OS, now when I start Task Manager and head over to Startup, it says BIOS time is 10 seconds but that is just not right unless the os boot time and BIOS time are different, does windows write the time from pressing the power on button to the time when the system is ready for use somewhere, to test this I had to watch a video on youtube where a system running on a hard drive vs a system running on ssd were started at the same time and a stopwatch started and the hard drive took more than 1 minute 30 seconds to boot into the OS but ssd took 29 seconds.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> it says BIOS time is 10 seconds but that is just not right unless the os boot time and BIOS time are different

They're completely different. The BIOS leaves when the OS starts booting, so your measured "wall clock" time is the *sum* of BIOS time and OS time.

---

Most likely Windows uses the CPU's [clock cycle counter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_Stamp_Counter) via `RDTSC` to detect the BIOS time (at least that's what systemd uses on Linux):

- At power-on, the TSC is always reset to zero (make that T<sub>1</sub>).
- As soon as the OS boot manager starts, it records the current TSC value (T<sub>2</sub>).
  Now T<sub>2</sub>−T<sub>1</sub> will be the number of CPU cycles it took for the BIOS to initialize.
- Later, the OS measures the number of CPU cycles per second (at the CPU's default frequency) to convert the cycle count into seconds and shows that as "BIOS time".

(The "systemd-boot" boot manager on Linux also records the TSC value immediately before giving control to the OS, to measure the time spent showing you the boot menu – though Windows probably doesn't do that.)

Some newer UEFI-based systems have a dedicated ACPI `FPDT` table where the firmware itself stores the "BIOS time" for the OS to pick up, but that's not yet universally supported.